# Bootstrap 4 - limit column height to another column height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have problem with limiting the height of one column to another column height. To explain: I have one column (class: list) with list of found items - maybe it will be one element, maybe 10 or 20. The second column is description of selected item - but I dont know the exact height - it depends on resolution, external data etc.

I want to set height of left column to the height of second column. When first column is bigger, I want to add scrollbar to show other items.

```css
.list {
    background: #f77;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content {
    background: #ccc;
    height: fit-content;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    
}

li {
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>bootstrap 4 column height</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container py-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 list">
            <ul>
                <li>element 1</li>
                <li>element 2</li>
                <li>element 3</li>
                <li>element 4</li>
                <li>element 5</li>
                <li>element 6</li>
                <li>element 7</li>
                <li>element 8</li>
                <li>element 9</li>
                <li>element 10</li>
                <li>element 11</li>
                <li>element 12</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 content">
            <div style="height: 400px; background: #eee">
                variable height content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Column add class `d-flex`,

```html
<div class="col-md-4 d-flex">
```

- Flexbox height is used to equalize.
- inside the `.box` class add `width: 100%` with you can adjust the width.

For example, https://codepen.io/yasinatesim/pen/NJgvYX